# How to Read Json in jquery

Tags: json

In below Example, how to access Required value of "DistributorInformation".
using Jquery.

```
{
    "Customization": {
        "DistributorInformation": {
            "Required": "true"
        },
        "PostRegistrationData": {
            "Required": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code what you already tried.

Comment: How you get that JSON, some file in your application or a rest services?

Comment: Why jQuery? Simple JavaScript: o.Customization.DistributorInformation.Required

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {
    "Customization": {
        "DistributorInformation": {
            "Required": "true"
        },
        "PostRegistrationData": {
            "Required": "false"
        }
    }
}
alert( o.Customization.DistributorInformation.Required);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like so:

```
    // if data is an object
    var data = {
        "Customization": {
            "DistributorInformation": {
                "Required": "true"
            },
            "PostRegistrationData": {
                "Required": "false"
            }
        }
    };
```

Or:

```
    // if data is a string
    var data = '{"Customization": {"DistributorInformation": {"Required": "true"},"PostRegistrationData": {"Required": "false"}}}';
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Then:

```
    var required = data.Customization.DistributorInformation.Required;

    console.log(required); // outputs "true"
```

You should be careful about using "true" or "false" since these values are strings and not boolean:

```
console.log(data.Customization.PostRegistrationData.Required == false)
```

will output `false`, so you should check like:

```
console.log(data.Customization.PostRegistrationData.Required == "false")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.parseJSON() function :

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{
          "Customization":{
                "DistributorInformation":{"Required":"true"},
                "PostRegistrationData":{"Required":"false"}
           }}' );

alert(obj.Customization.DistributorInformation.Required);
```